# Failure of endpoint after deployment to AWS using Zappa

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask-restful, zappa

I tried the quick start examples and deployed them all to the aws and they worked as expected. After I deployed my project, it did not work with unhelpful message when hitting the endpoint:

```
{"message": "An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command."
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):
File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 433, in handler
response=Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ)
File \"/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 903, in from_app
return cls(*_run_wsgi_app(app, environ, buffered)
File \"/var/task/werkzeug/test.py\", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
app_rv = app(environ, start_response)",
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"
]}
```

I checked AWS, and everythign is there, the API gateway endpoint proxy, the lambda function and the role.

Here is my zappa_settings file

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "main.app",
        "aws_region": "eu-west-2",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-sodos"
    }
}
```

Here is the zappa tail (some data were masked wit xxx for security):

```
[1499618707646] [DEBUG] 2017-07-09T16:45:07.628Z f724d3cf-64c5-11e7-a037-b7a389f86726 Zappa Event: {'resource': '/{proxy+}', 'path': '/v1/article', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer': 'true', 'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer': 'false', 'CloudFront-Viewer-Country': 'xx', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host': 'xxxxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'origin': 'chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop', 'postman-token': 'xxxxx-636e-cb61-1da6-xxx', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 'Via': '2.0 xxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'xxxx-cUUCbAyGS1Xhy5fb_mdmt-xxxx==', 'X-Amzn-Trace-Id': 'Root=1-xxxx-xxxx', 'X-Forwarded-For': '195.142.175.59,
54.240.145.78', 'X-Forwarded-Port': '443', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https'}, 'queryStringParameters': None, 'pathParameters': {'proxy': 'v1/article'}, 'stageVariables': None, 'requestContext': {'path': '/dev/v1/article', 'accountId': 'xxxx', 'resourceId': 'xxxx', 'stage': 'dev', 'requestId': 'f71da6ed-64c5-11e7-b70f-bbc6fe021ea4', 'identity': {'cognitoIdentityPoolId': None, 'accountId': None, 'cognitoIdentityId': None, 'caller': None, 'apiKey': '', 'sourceIp': '195.142.175.59', 'accessKey': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationType': None, 'cognitoAuthenticationProvider': None, 'userArn': None, 'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 'user': None}, 'resourcePath': '/{proxy+}', 'httpMethod': 'POST', 'apiId': 'xxxxx'}, 'body': 'dXJsPWh0dHAlM0ElMkYlMkZhcmFiaTIxLmNvbSUyRnN0b3J5JTJGMTAxOTM4OCUyRiUyNUQ4JTI1QTMlMjVEOSUyNTg4JTI1RDklMjU4NC0lMjVEOCUyNUFEJTI1RDklMjU4MyUyNUQ5JTI1ODUtJTI1RDklMjU4MiUyNUQ4JTI1QjYlMjVEOCUyNUE3JTI1RDglMjVBNiUyNUQ5JTI1OEEtJTI1RDglMjVBOCUyNUQ4JTI1QjQlMjVEOCUyNUEzJTI1RDklMjU4Ni0lMjVEOSUyNTg1JTI1RDglMjVBRCUyNUQ4JTI1QTclMjVEOSUyNTg4JTI1RDklMjU4NCUyNUQ4JTI1QTktJTI1RDglMjVBNyUyNUQ5JTI1ODQlMjVEOCUyNUE3JTI1RDklMjU4NiUyNUQ5JTI1ODIlMjVEOSUyNTg0JTI1RDglMjVBNyUyNUQ4JTI1QTgtJTI1RDglMjVBNyUyNUQ5JTI1ODQlMjVEOSUyNTgxJTI1RDglMjVBNyUyNUQ4JTI1QjQlMjVEOSUyNTg0JTI1RDglMjVBOS0lMjVEOSUyNTgxJTI1RDklMjU4QS0lMjVEOCUyNUFBJTI1RDglMjVCMSUyNUQ5JTI1ODMlMjVEOSUyNThBJTI1RDglMjVBNw==',
'isBase64Encoded': True}
[1499618707646] 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

- Zappa version used: 0.42.2
- Operating System and Python version: OS X El Capitan, Python 3.6.1

The output of `pip freeze`:

```
aniso8601==1.2.1
argcomplete==1.8.2
base58==0.2.4
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.40
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.4 click==6.7
cssselect==1.0.1
docutils==0.13.1
durationpy==0.4
feedfinder2==0.0.4
feedparser==5.2.1
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
future==0.16.0
futures==3.1.1
hjson==2.0.7
idna==2.5
itsdangerous==0.24
jieba3k==0.35.1
Jinja2==2.9.6
jmespath==0.9.3
kappa==0.6.0
lambda-packages==0.15.1
lxml==3.8.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
newspaper3k==0.2.2
nltk==3.2.4
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.2.1
placebo==0.8.1
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-slugify==1.2.4
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.1
requests-file==1.4.2
s3transfer==0.1.10
six==1.10.0
tldextract==2.1.0
toml==0.9.2
tqdm==4.14.0
troposphere==1.9.4
Unidecode==0.4.21
urllib3==1.21.1
Werkzeug==0.12
wsgi-request-logger==0.4.6
zappa==0.42.2
-e git+https://github.com/xxxx/bc_utilities.git@xxxx#egg=bc_utilities
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get Zappa tail

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/795 contains a list of things to try that has worked for different folks in the community.

One common issue is related to using slim_handler, but according to your zappa_config.js, that does not apply to your case.

Another common issue has to do with the .pyc files getting bundled into the zip package. Try deleting .pyc files in your local project folder before calling zappa update and see if that addresses the issue for you.